# FragmentTabHost run Fragment onCreateView after press back

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

I have activity A with FragmentTabHost and activity B. Suppose I go from activity A to activity B via Intent. And then, when I press back button I go to activity A, but Fragment's onCreateView doesn't called. Why? How I can run this method manually?